# Do I Need To Make A Class Diagram For All Object Instances and Microsoft Methods That I Use?

Tags: uml, sdlc

I have the following classes made in C# in a program called MyGrades:

```
Menu.cs
Grade.cs
Student.cs
```

I have the following instances in my Student class:

```
 private Grade test = new Grade(300);
 private Grade hwQz = new Grade(700);
```

In Menu.cs I use the following Microsoft methods and Microsoft Class respectively:

```
Console.Clear()
Console.WriteLine()
Console.Write()
Console.ReadKey()

ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
```

In Grade.cs I use the following Microsoft methods:

```
Console.Clear()
Console.WriteLine()
Console.Write()
Console.ReadKey
```

Do I need to make class diagrams for Console as well as for all my class instances?

Answer (score 0):

The programming language doesn't require you to draw a class diagram.

If your course instructor requires you to draw diagrams, you'll need to ask them exactly what they want.

Generally you should include other classes when they are relevant to understanding the diagram.  It is not useful to have everything point to, say, the Logging class.  If something especially interacts with the Console that might be relevant.

Comment: My instructor is very brief and hard to get ahold of.  I am doing a  full SDLC project.  I understand it all except if I am to include this stuff; I am aloof.  I remember him saying something about the Microsoft classes but we've never practice this in class.  I just dont know how I would include the Microsoft Classes and my class instances in the class diagram.  We never went over this.  What would maintain the class instances and the Microsoft classes? Would they be an aggregate?  Any advice would help.

Comment: What do you even mean by "what would maintain the class instances?"

Comment: I meant more along the lines of the Microsoft Classes.  Im using Astah for my class diagrams.  Maintains is the arrow on the relationship line that describes what objects are communicating with eachother.

Comment: So the short answer is, I don't think you should try to describe how the system classes internally relate.  That is not relevant.

Comment: For the future, how much rep do I need to add a tag?  There is no tag for class diagrams nor Astah.  I went on a whim by putting UML because class diagrams is not UML.